# LoadViewState not called on PostBack Event

Tags: asp.net, .net, datagrid, viewstate, control-state

I have a page which has a datagrid and a dropdown apart from other stuff on it in a special area of the page ( say appArea) which is loaded in desktopArea div.

The dropdown is supposed to reload the datagrid when its SelectedIndexChanged is handled which is working well.

Upon some resize threshold being reached, I am moving this appArea into another location ( say mobileArea div as I have to show the same area with event binding and etc. intact) with this snippet below.

```
                var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
                $(wrapper).append($appArea.detach());
                $(wrapper).find('script').remove();
                $("wikiAppArea").parent().empty().append($(wrapper).children().contents());
```

Upon moving this appArea into mobileArea div, if I change the dropdown values, the SelectedIndexChanged postback event is called and datagrid is binded but the datagrid is lost.

Doing a trace on the page reveals that in the case when datagrid is lost upon dropdown click, DataGrid does not call the LoadViewState method at all ( The SaveViewState and TrackViewState are being called).

From initial investigation, it looks like the control hierarchy is changing and that is causing some issue in that during postback the LoadViewState for the DataGrid is not called.

Is there a way to force LoadViewState to be called in this case.

Comment: The datagrid is overriding the SaveViewState and LoadViewState methods.

The TrackViewState has not been overriden in the DataGrid

Answer (score 1):

Turns out applying the ViewStateModeById Attribute fixed this.

The ViewStateModeByIdAttribute class is used to specify a control that requires view-state loading by ID. The default view-state loading behavior is for ASP.NET to load the view-state information for a control by its index in the control tree of the page. There is a performance cost for loading view-state information by ID because the page control tree must be searched for the control specifically before loading its view-state information.

The ViewStateModeByIdAttribute class does not apply to saving the view-state information for a control.
The ViewStateModeByIdAttribute class metadata attribute is valid only on class declarations.